# Determine at which points $f(x)=[x]$ has a limit

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis

Let $[x]$ denote the largest integer that is less than or equal to x. Determine at which points $f(x)=[x]$ has a limit. I know that I'm suppose to use the epsilon definition of a limit to do but I'm not quite sure how to finish it. I'm assuming that that f(x) only has a limit at non-integer values??
For every $\epsilon >0$, there exists $\delta>0 $ such that $0<|x-x_0|<\delta$, so $|f(x)-f(x_0)|<\epsilon$, where $|[x]-[x_0]|<\epsilon$

Comment: Can you graph $ [x] $?

Comment: It is easier with left-right limits.

Comment: I don't get what the problem is, near $x_0$ we have $f(x)=f(x_0)$, so you can pick $\delta = \epsilon$

Comment: conversely, near the integers you're going to have $|f(x) - f(x_0)|=1$ on the left